# Python Config File with Sensitive Arguments

Tags: python, github, encryption

I have a publicly hosted repository on GitHub which I require to manage updates for scripts on my server. I would like my scripts to call some sensitive arguments automatically, however I don't want those arguments to be public.

My thoughts are to .gitignore a config file with my sensitive arguments and manually copy the config file when installing. Alternatively I was thinking of including an encrypted config file in the GitHub repository and manually inputting the hash as an environmental arg on my server.

What is the best practice to achieve the outcome? Am I missing something completely? Any info or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Config files are *supposed* to be created and/or modified upon installation; if they exist in your repository at all, they should be essentially empty, maybe with comments describing what values your scripts can recognized and accept. The actual values for the config file should be stored, if at all, in a local configuration management system.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a config file to .gitignore and manually copying it over is a commonly used approach and is fine. I'd say the most common approach is to use environment variables, although you'd still have to manually configure them on your server. [Here's a short article](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b) with some good examples on these approaches.